# Absolute Positioning with Inputs in Android 2.2 Web Browser

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

It seems that android decides to overlay inputs when they are focused with another input...

Because of this it is destroying layouts, for example if you view this image

[image: Android 2.2 Positing Issue]

There are only TWO inputs in the DOM so i'm not sure where or how android is manipulating this input to draw it on the screen.

So what I am trying to do is remove the floating input which is drawn on the screen for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code from this question:

```
input[type=text]
{
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

However i noticed passwords would still have an overlay, so to fix this i chagned the input field from a Password field to a text field and applied the following css:

```
input.passwordField {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

[Disable Android browser's input overlays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423101/disable-android-browsers-input-overlays)

Comment: Unfortunately setting webkit-user-modify to plaintext seems to break all of my 'advanced' keyboard features like Swype, holding backspace to delete a word, special keyboard layouts for numbers/phone numbers, etc. The other styles don't seem to make much difference (with or without webkit-user-modify). Seems like a big oversight on the parts of the Android browser developers. :(

Comment: This is correct. Android 4.1 fixes these issues, but Android 2.x doesn't work and Android 4.0 only works slightly. More info here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24746