# disable webview input field duplicates java

Tags: java, android, html, cordova, webview

Android seems to add a duplicate input upon focus ontop of the current, due to nature of different devices css hacks seem to fix them in certain devices and not others, is there a method that can be attached via java to stop it from adding the native input field into the html document?

This seems to be the exact problem:

[Disable Android browser's input overlays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423101/disable-android-browsers-input-overlays)

However the css fixes do not work across every device...