# Textarea issue with -webkit-user-modify on Phonegap application(disappearing keyboard)

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, textarea

I'm developing application in Phonegap and have some styles on my textarea:

```
    textarea {
     background: url(img/ynxjD.png) repeat-y;
     width: 600px;
     height: 300px;
     font: normal 14px verdana;
     line-height: 25px;
     padding: 2px 10px;
     border: solid 1px #ddd;
    }
```

Because Android browse has default styles on input elements and textarea like overlays and basically when I click on my textarea all styles dissappear and big ugly white rectangle with green corners appears, I found a workaround with this:

```
    textarea {
        -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    }
```

as mentioned here:
[Disable Android browser's input overlays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423101/disable-android-browsers-input-overlays)
Everything is great, but when I write in the textarea and go to new line android keyboard dissapears and I need to click again to appear and that is with every new line.

I am testing on HTC desire X if that matters
I would be glad if someone help me fix this : )