# Android text input in a webview shows a second box

Tags: android, cordova, webview, kendo-ui

I'm developing an application for Android (and iOS) using PhoneGap, and have come across a problem where as a result of some `-webkit-transform: translate3d(x,y,z);` calls, my text input boxes that are created by Android are no longer lined up with the element on the page.

The issue that I'm experiencing is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347078/android-webview-input-boxes-doubled), however I wish to hide the boxes that Android creates and instead use the ones that are present within my application's DOM.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [specific article](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/forms) about Android form bugs in our documentation, check it out. Unfortunately there is no full solution for this problem, but at least the newer Kendo UI Mobile versions implement a partial workaround for this issue (which btw was finally fixed in Jelly Bean). Since the workaround has several negative effects, consider if you want to use it at all.

Comment: Thanks, this has put me onto the right track! (I am yet to have enough rep to upvote, otherwise I would have)