# jQuery Mobile iScrollView error

Tags: performance, cordova, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, iscrollview

I am using jQuery Mobile and iScrollview together,
I used [iscrollView](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview)

The scrolling work fine.

**Problem 1:**

when I click on a input text/password field, I get an extra box overlapping the whole elements, which has the same content as the input.
same problem found in

[here no solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206751/jquery-mobile-iscrollview-issue-with-android-2-3-4)

**Problem 2:**

when navigating to next page, the previous page remains behind new page and when tap the mobile screen the previous page goes off from the device. this is not happening in the webbrowsers.
Any suggestions,

code for main.js

```
 require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../lib/jquery',
        'jquery.mobile-config': 'helper/jqm-config',
        'jquery.mobile': '../lib/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min',
        underscore: '../lib/underscore-min',
        backbone: '../lib/backbone-min',
        templates: '../templates',
        text: 'helper/text',
        config: 'helper/config',
        'backbone.subroute': '../lib/backbone.subroute',
        'cookie': '../lib/jquery.cookie',
         'maskInput': '../lib/Jquerymaskinput',
        'iscroll': '../lib/iscroll',
        'iscrollview': '../lib/jquery.mobile.iscrollview',
            }
    ,
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: "_"
        },
        'backbone': {
            //These script dependencies should be loaded before loading
            //backbone.js
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the
            //module value.
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'jquery.mobile-config': ['jquery'],
        'jquery.mobile': ['jquery', 'jquery.mobile-config'],
        'backbone.subroute': ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
        //'backbone.oauth':['jquery','underscore','backbone'],
        'iscroll': {
            deps: ['jquery.mobile']
        },
        'iscrollview': {
            deps: ['iscroll']
        },
        'config': {
            exports: 'Config'
        }

    }

});
requirejs(['jquery', 'iscroll', 'jquery.mobile', 'iscrollview'], function($, iScroll) {
    var elements = jQuery(document).find(":jqmData(iscroll)");
    elements.iscrollview();
    
});

require([
    'app'

], function(App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

for router

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'backbone.subroute'
], function($, _, Backbone) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            // general routes 
            '': 'defaultAction',
            'login':'login',               
            'menu': 'mainMenu',        
           
            // Default
            '*actions': 'defaultAction'       
        }
    });
  
    var initialize = function() {

            $('.back').live('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                window.history.back();
                return false;
            });

        var app_router = new AppRouter;       
        app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function(actions) {
            require(['views/home/register'], function(RegisterView) {
                // We have no matching route, lets display the home page 
                console.log('At defaultAction');
            var registerView = new RegisterView();
            registerView.render();
               /// this.changePage(loginView, 'slide');
            });
        });          
         app_router.on('route:login', function(actions) {
            require(['views/home/login'], function(LoginView) {
                // We have no matching route, lets display the home page 
                console.log('At defaultAction');
            var loginView = new LoginView();
            loginView.render();
               /// this.changePage(loginView, 'slide');
            });
        });
        app_router.on('route:mainMenu', function(actions) {
            require(['views/home/menu'], function(MainMenuView) {
                console.log('At mainMenu::router');
            var mainMenuView = new MainMenuView();
            mainMenuView.render();
              //  this.changePage(mainMenuView, 'slide');
    });
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Comment: Is this of any help https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/119 ??

Comment: use
input {
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
but not working.??

Comment: The link has more solutions. Have you tried them?

Comment: similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347078/android-webview-input-boxes-doubled
but if i use  input { -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; } the keypad doesnt goes off :-(

Comment: On which browser/phone do these problem occur? Are using custom css? can you post some code?

Comment: @Omar Android 4.0.3 actually problem when using iscrollview, when remove it, there is no problem

Comment: How do you load js libraries in `head`? only Android?

Comment: backbone with requirejs

Comment: I meant the order of loading js libraries. Posting more details will motivate others to assist you.

Comment: have you tried `.trigger('updatelayout')` on `click` and `pageshow` when navigating?

Comment: on router.js page? I'm using backbone routing.

Comment: Aren't you using JQM events? I'm not router nor backbone expert :/ _lo siento amigo_

Comment: cant integrate jqm events with router?

Comment: I've no idea, can u guide ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30250/discussion-between-omar-and-anonmous-change)

Comment: any luck? i'm on chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrite the codes but, its more or less solved my problem updated the jqm to 1.3 and jquery to 1.9.
rewrite all css files.
Navigation to next page is fine
and at least its working now.

Thanks to Omar who helped me.

gracias mi amigo

Comment: @Omar puede ayudar con mi problema reciente, amigo?

Comment: por favor, eche un vistazo a este
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909603/jquerymobile-numerical-keypad-phonegap