# jquerymobile numerical keypad phonegap

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-button

I'm using jquerymobile, but can't get the keypad to only show numeric keys (including decimals). Only default keypad is shown.I'm using phonegap, 
I use

```
<input type="number">
```

the problem is that the numpad is shown but when i use

```
input {-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;}
```

the default keypad is only shown.
Any suggestion would be great.

Thankx.

Comment: http://www.bielousov.com/2012/android-label-text-appears-in-input-field-as-a-placeholder/

Comment: @Sam where to add line breaks

Comment: try to remove `-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;` gains `focus` and on `blur` add it back. what do you think?

Comment: @Omar if -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; is removed on focus then no use of it on input box, on blur on need of it?

Comment: I mean the problem is caused by `-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;` right? and at the same time if fixes duplicate input problem. So if you removed it on input `focus`, the numpad will popup instead of the alpha keyboard. Once the input loses focus (`blur`), add it back in order not to face any problem with duplicate input.

Comment: if -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; removed on input focus, then  it dont  fixes duplicate input problem.
Duplicate input aries only on focus.

Comment: maybe u can use `setTimeout` to remove it.

Comment: can u enlight with few line of code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31178/discussion-between-omar-and-anonmous-change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$('#<element-id>').focus();`

Comment: Can you give some more details on which platforms you are working on mobile?